# android. how to track on/off the phone?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, action

I want track when going inclusion/shutdown(one from two) the telephone.
Probably, I must use BroadcastReceiver. I found action for intent - ACTION_SHUTDOWN. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN

But, I am not sure that is will be work when I remove my battery from device. Are there action for inclusion device?

I am not want  to use Service...

Comment: Are you trying to detect when the battery is removed? You can't detect when battery is removed.. the phone simply stops working...

Comment: @DanielMendel No. I want know when my phone will be shut down or will be included that to change boolean variable in my project. What I must use? Service?